# HTML webview browser in Flutter: Zooming like in Desktop

Tags: flutter, webview

Let's open google.com in Google Chrome.

On *Desktop*, when we press **Ctrl/Cmd-➕**, the content gets enlarged and the page gets re-layout ("responsive design").

On *Mobile*, when we **pinch to zoom**, the content gets enlarged, but the page's layout stays the same. Instead, the page becomes bigger than the viewport (screen) so we have to drag around to see other areas of the page.

How to have zoom behavior in Flutter webview that works like in Desktop?

I use `flutter_inappwebview`. `initialScale` zooms everything on the page but overflows the viewport.

I'm fine to use any other library that supports my use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;

  MyWebView({required this.url});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(url)),
        gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
          Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
          ),
          Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
            () => ScaleGestureRecognizer(),
          ),
        ].toSet(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using InAppWebView widget and pass in a set of gestureRecognizers that include a ScaleGestureRecognizer and a VerticalDragGestureRecognizer. ScaleGestureRecognizer is used for zooming in and out, and the VerticalDragGestureRecognizer is used for scrolling vertically.

So the webview should respond to pinch-to-zoom gestures on mobile devices in the same way that desktop browsers do, scalling the content without overflowing the viewport.

Hope this helps.